# EJB3 - How to access EJB3 from JAVA SE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am new to EJB3, I have created a remote EJB3 and running the same in GlassFish application server, now I am trying to access the same using my Java SE application, I have referred many links, I am not able to successfully execute my `lookup` statement, I am getting exception like no such resource available.

Please let me the exact detail procedure to access my EJB3 which is running inside GlassFish application server.

Answer (score 0):

j2se can also access the EJB3 application, you should use the massage entity to call you EJB service.